# i would like to center a div inside another div but not working?

Tags: css, html

```css
#first {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #94b8b8;
}
#second {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="first">
    <div id="second">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How to get it i want the second div in the exact center of the first div but it is not even visible. how achieve this without using left, top attributes.
note:i wants align it only using css but not using  tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: kindly provide fiddle link plz

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to do what you want:

```css
.outer {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
.inner {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" align="center">
  <div class="inner">
    Deprecated (use css)
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="position: relative; left: 50%; margin-left: -50px;">
    :)
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer" style="position: relative">
  <div class="inner" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -50px;">
    :)
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Another solution**

```
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: but i dont want the align property in the html . in css there is align option?

Comment: @mystylecoder in that case choose one of other three solutions

Answer (score 0):

To center absolutely positioned div with known width, you can use this:

```
.inner1 {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Or, if you need to center it both horizontally and vertically:

```
.inner2 {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

If width of inner is unknown - use css3 transforms:

```
.inner3 {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 0;

}
```

Ant for vertical centering also:

```
.inner4 {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4qxpc0ua/

Answer (score 0):

calculate the top and left position and apply it for the second div.

```
   #first {
     position: relative;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-color: #94b8b8;
   }
   #second {
     position: absolute;
     width: 15%;
     height: 15%;
     left:42.5%; //50% - (15% / 2)
     top:42.5%; //50% - (15% / 2)
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-color: blue;
   }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/3u8v01b4/4/)